# pthreads: wait until read() returns a value > 0

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, conditional-statements, wait

I'm working on a client program that will operate as a basic instant messenger. I'm using pthread to to open up a thread dedicated to waiting for a message to be received and the the message to be read. Is using pthread_cond_wait the correct way to go about waiting for `read(sockfd, buffer, 256)` to be above 0?

```
void *threadRead() {
  while (1) {
    bzero(buffer,256);
    pthread_cond_wait(&buffer_lock, read(sockfd, buffer, 255) > 0);
    n = read(sockfd, buffer, 255);
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
  }
}
```

You see I just need to wait until `read()` comes back with a value above `0` to continue and I can't find the right system to do that. If anyone could link something that would put me on the right track or give me a hint that would be great.

Comment: That's not how you do it. You need to use `select()` to wait for input on the socket.

Answer (score 1):

No.  `pthread_cond_wait()` is for waiting on a condition that will be changed by one of your other threads.

If you just want to wait for `read()` to return something, just call `read()`.  Unless you have specifically marked the socket as non-blocking, it will block the calling thread until there is something to return.

If `read()` ever returns 0 then it indicates end of file: it means that the socket has been closed on the remote side, so there will never be any more to read.

Comment: calling read() in a while loop would seem really intensive on the system. I'm just looking for some way to read out the buffer/message if and when it comes through.

Comment: It's not intensive if it blocks waiting, it just blocks. You can always sleep too!

Comment: @user3475821: It isn't - blocking means that the calling thread is suspended until some event occurs (in this case, until there is activity on the socket).

Comment: @caf that sounds like just what I'm looking for but I can't find the specific function you're talking about. everything I've seen requires another thread or function to pass a signal or notify. I'm just waiting for a value to be present.

Comment: @user3475821: The `read()` function itself - as long as the socket is blocking, which is the default - does that.  (If the socket is non-blocking, you can use `select()` or `poll()`).

Comment: ... wow I'm an idiot, the socket blocks by default. well that makes my entire question redundant unless other users have similar problems.

Answer (score -1):

You should use [`select()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) instead, like this

```
int running;
running = 1;
while (running != 0) /* Just in case you want to end the loop, you can */
{
    fd_set rdset;
    struct timeval timeout;

    timeout.tv_sec = NUMBER_OF_SECONDS_TO_WAIT;
    timeout.tv_usec = YOU_CAN_HAVE_MICRO_SECONDS_PRECISION;

    FD_ZERO(&rdset);
    FD_SET(fd, &rdset);
    if (select(fd + 1, &rdset, NULL, NULL, &timeout) == 1)
    {
        ssize_t length;
        char buffer[100];
        length = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        /* use buffer now */
    }
    else
    {
        /* Timed out and still nothing to read */
        /* do something meanwhile and retry if */
        /* you want to.                        */
    }
    running = use_a_function_to_check_this();
}
```

you can use it in a different thread, but you need to be careful.

Non-blocking IO is difficult, it doesn't matter how you implement it is hard.

One more thing, this

```
n = read(sockfd, buffer, 255);
printf("%s\n",buffer);
```

is likely undefined behavior, since apparently buffer is

```
char buffer[256];
```

you could

```
n = read(sockfd, buffer, 255 /* or sizeof(buffer) - 1 */);
buffer[n] = '\0';

printf("%s\n",buffer);
```

ensuring that `buffer` is `nul` terminated.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is read out messages when and if they come from a server to the client. the port number and socket are taken care of, I just need some way of detecting whether a message has been sent of not, if not, wait for a message to come. then print it out. I'm not sure how this code would do that.

Comment: If you pass `NULL` to `select()` as the timeout parameter it will wait until there is something to read. Just read the manual and you will understand, and pay special attention to details if you are on linux.

Comment: Okay it's beginning to make more sense the more I read the manual, I'm just confused about the entire fd+1 part, where did you get fd from?

Comment: It's the socket, the file descriptor you are using to write to the socket. You should pass to `select()` the maximum value of the file descriptors in the set + 1.